# Is it possible to restrict access via CanCan & Rolify within RailsAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am using Devise, Rolify and CanCan for my authentication & authorization.

I am also using RailsAdmin for my `superadmin`.

But, I would like to grant access to my other roles (say `admin`, `agent`, `client`).

Where each of those roles will only have access to some models/features within RailsAdmin.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wiki on github. Read that https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan

Comment: Thanks. I glossed over this.